# Unable to compile header bits/stdc++11 with g++

Tags: c++11, g++

Compiling the program below on windows with `g++ file.cpp -std=c++11`

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int x = 0;
    cout << x;
    return 0;
}
```

gives an error that you can see on link below (unable to post error here due to stackoverflow's *too much code in comparison to text* constraint, sorry for posting it this way!)

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4w9GgJk2CmjdGg0TjluWElNRTQ/view

```
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\postypes.h:40:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\iosfwd:40,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ios:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\istream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\sstream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\complex:45,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ccomplex:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\mingw32\bits\stdc++.h:52,
                 from template.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:177:11: error: '::wcscat' has not been declared
   using ::wcscat;
           ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:178:11: error: '::wcscmp' has not been declared
   using ::wcscmp;
...
```

Any pointers where this is going wrong? (Using gcc 5.3)

Comment: Including that header is a bad idea in general: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use std=gnu++11

```
g++ file.cpp -std=gnu++11
```